# How to get slotted elements?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I need to interact with a slotted element as soon as it is slotted. I tried the following:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

const $slot = ref<HTMLSlotElement | null>(null);

onMounted(() => console.log($slot.value?.assignedElements()[0]));
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <slot ref="$slot"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

However, when I render this component with slotted children I just get `undefined` in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Give your slot a name instead of a ref and access slots using the [`useSlot()`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#useslots-useattrs) helper.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useSlots, onMounted } from 'vue';

const slots = useSlots();

onMounted(() => {
  if (slots && slots.$slot) {
    console.log('slots.$slot()', slots.$slot());
  }
});

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="$slot"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Once slot content is given by a parent component you'll find that `slots.$slot()` contains an array of the virtual DOM nodes that make up the slot's content

Comment: That helps a lot but how can I get the actual slotted DOM element?